# How to add an array to a already created JSON file?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I needed help adding an array to a JSON file that is already created. I am using PHP to try and do this.

Right now this is my code:

```
$profile = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=0CDB935B8BFF1E1664C90DB875E88727&steamids={$steam64}");
$buffer = fopen("cache/players/{$steam64}.json", "w+");
fwrite($buffer, $profile);
fclose($buffer);
        }
```

It gets data from an external JSON file, then creates and writes to a new file. After that the code looks like this:

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198064105349",
        }
    ]

}
}
```

Now I want to add an array in, I tried this:

```
$data[] = array('tradelink'=>'', 'paypalemail'=>'');

file_put_contents($buffer, json_encode($data));
```

But it did nothing. I put this code in right after it added and wrote to the new JSON file.

If anyone can help me add an array into a JSON file it would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: `array_Push($mainArray, $newArray)` ?

Comment: So do you want to add the array to the existing JSON structure and get valid JSON, or do you want to just append the array to the file, and get invalid JSON? If the former, you have to decode the existing JSON and add to that, and then encode it and write it back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file, using json_decode, then append the array, then using json_encode again.

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($buffer));
 $data->tradelink = "";
 $data->paypalemail = "";
 file_put_contents($buffer, json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not associating you buffer object with the array you want to put in.
This code will work.

```
$profile = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=0CDB935B8BFF1E1664C90DB875E88727&steamids={$steam64}"); 
$buffer = json_decode(file_get_contents($profile));
$buffer->data = array('tradelink'=>'', 'paypalemail'=>'');
file_put_contents(json_encode($buffer));
```